# How can I download a csv file directly on my server

Tags: php, csv, upload, download

my task is easy but I can't find anything on the web to help me.

I click on a button on my website, this event execute a php file (by ajax).

In this php file, I want to download a csv files directly on my serveur in the folder /uploads. I have the link of the csv, exemple : www.thewebsite.com/files/yourlastcall.csv

I have access to this folder, and I have all the rights in my /uploads.

So, do you guys know how to achieve this?

Thank you, and sorry for my english, i'm a little frenchy :)

Comment: And if I can change the name of the file, it will be just perfect :)

Comment: Checkout: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: I dont think its possible with AJax...see here....this will definitely help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: Kylek, I don't want to move the file on the computer of the client ;-) See the answer of Joel above this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
$url = 'http://website.com/linktofile.csv';
$source = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file/newfilename.csv', $source);
```

Edit: Of course, that's just the PHP part. I'm assuming you know how to make an AJAX call already, in jQuery or similarly.

Comment: Sound's Awesome, and yes the rest of the task I am ok with it :) I will accept your answer in 10mins !

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://website.com/linktofile.csv';
$source = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file/newfilename.csv', $source);
```

thanks to Joel Hinz